# Do all stem cells have a full number of chromosomes?

Tags: chromosome, stem-cells

Do all or only some stem cells have a full number of chromosomes?

Comment: Are you attempting to distinguish between totipotent and pluripotent stem cells here?

Comment: Not really, but is that one of the differences between totipotent and pluripotent stem cells? (one has a full number of chromosomes and the other has half the full number of chromosomes)

Comment: I guess I'm just confused by your question. What causes you to think stem cells wouldn't have a full set of chromosomes, since by definition they're the cells that can differentiate into many different types of cells, which means they generally need all that genetic information.  People have created artificial haploid stem cells, but I don't know if that's what you're trying to get at. And how would you count something like a muscle cell, that has many nuclei?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I also thought that it would make sense for them to have a full set of chromosomes, but I just read it somewhere (that stem cells don't have a full set of chromosomes) and so I thought maybe only some had half the full set and some didn't so I decided to ask to make sure. Well, thanks for the help. I guess they were (somehow) referring to the artificial haploid stem cells. It seems like I don't know enough about this topic so I'll just read about it more.